# PHP password_verify() does not verify successfully

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hash

I have checked all the similar questions and answers but none is working for me.
I am using the standard php hashing and verification method Below are my codes.

this the code for hashing the password

```html
$passwordhash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

the hashed output is then stored into a mysql database table  the column is varchar datatype with size 255.

When the hash is retrieved and verified with a user presented password the verification returns a false.

the code for the verification is presented below.

```html
 if($rows2['user_name'] == $username) && password_verify($password ,$rows2['password'])){

  
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session

} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
```

however a verification of the hash with a correct password before storage provides a true answer.

here is the code for the verification before storage

```html
if(password_verify($pwd ,$hashpassword )){

 echo "<BR>"." the internal verify before storage"."<BR>";
}
```

this is the code for the storage of the hashed password.

```css
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "datacentre";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname , 3306);
    

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

 //mysql_select_db("$database", $con);
 $sql= "INSERT INTO admin (user_name , password , time_created)
VALUES ('$u_name' , '$hash' , NOW() )"; 


if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

$con->close();
```

This is the code for retrieving the hashed password.

```css
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database , 3306);


// Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
 die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
                             }

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);


// Retrieve data from database

$sql="select * from admin where user_name ='$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  while($rows2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){


  if($rows2['user_name'] == $username) && password_verify($password ,$rows2['password'])){

  
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session

} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

}

$con->close(); // Closing Connection             

      }

}


}
```

looks like the problem is with how the database stores the hashed password. 
Please will need a solution.

Comment: If you suspect the database storing the hash incorrectly, you can try to change the data type to binary.

Comment: am aware about the variables name  its ok cos i am using different php files

Comment: @frz3993 When I check the hashed password in the database table the hashed password is the same as the one generated. So will the storage as binary actually change a thing.